# Learning material for boot configuration

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I really need a comprehensive, yet clearly explained reference regarding how all the boot configuration, structure and execution comes together in Linux and how it is compared to Windows and all the nuts and bolts of the multiple boot mode in terms of boot loader installation, re-installation and configuration. I'm just sick of loosing gigs of data because of lack of essential knowledge so any links/references will be appreciated!

best regards,
Mike

Comment: The things you are asking for (boot config, multiple boots etc) have nothing to do with "loosing gigs of data". The latter you solve by creating backups. Besides that I would advice to create a partition with a clear label so that during re-partitioning you see what NOT to format. But even then.. backups are a must-have.

Comment: @Creator too broad != off-topic. In this case the question is broad, but linking to references on the Web is easy and manageable. Just a lot to read through, but if you study CS or doin' the computers is your hobby, you should have read half of that already. I commend everyone how does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UEFI boot: how does that actually work, then?](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) is still a good read for understanding UEFI. Even if you don't have a UEFI capable machine, start with this article.

After that you can read through and compare the articles on [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#The_BIOS_boot_process) as well as [Windows NT startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process) and [Linux startup process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process). The [UEFI article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UEFI) on the Arch Wiki is a good cheat sheet to look up how to do certain things, but remember that some of these are Arch specific, but as Arch intents to teach users how configuration is done, this isn't bad, just lenghty.

I completely agree with Rinzwind's comment: make and verify backups!